# How to type an "@" character in a Jupyter Notebook on a Mac

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, data-entry

I just tried to enter an "@" character in a Jupyter Notebook on a Mac by `ALT`+`g` which is the standard MAC way to type the at-sign. However, instead of inserting an "@" The "Jump to line:" input dialog was triggered in the active cell. How can an "@" be typed inside a Jupyter Notebook cell? One example where this is needed is function decorators.

Unbinding the key as by the by the documentation seems to fail in my setting. https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/keymaps.html

```json
{
  ...,
  "keys": {
    "edit": {
      "unbind": [
        "alt-g"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The `Settings` > `Advanced Settings Editor` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` notes that

```json
    // Note: To disable a system default shortcut,
    // copy it to User Preferences and add the
    // "disabled" key, for example:
    // {
    //     "command": "application:activate-next-tab",
    //     "keys": [
    //         "Ctrl Shift ]"
    //     ],
    //     "selector": "body",
    //     "disabled": true
    // }
```

but using

```json
{
    "shortcuts": [
        {
            "command": "editmenu:go-to-line",
            "keys": [
                "Alt G"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode",
            "disabled": true            
        }
    ]
}
```

does not actually unset the `Alt G` key binding.

I know copy-pasting the @ character works, but that is not a solution.

Comment: Experienced on a 13" MacBookPro with builtin keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your keyboard - I am assuming you don't have an @ symbol on it!

You could unbind the `CMD + g` shortcut: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/keymaps.html

Comment: This seems to be a good way to go, but I fail to implement that. I tried adding `,
  "keys": {
    "edit": {
      "unbind": [
        "Alt-G"
      ]
    }
  }` to the `.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`, but that this does not work even after restarting jupyter lab and reloading the website with disabled cache. I also tried to change the "Advanced Settings Editor" and adding "{
    {
        "command": "editmenu:go-to-line",
        "keys": [
            "Alt G"
        ],
        "selector": "body",
        "disabled": true,
    }
}"